# Is it possible to patch value for FormArray that is in FormGroup.?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am new to reactive form. I am not sure if I can update the FormArray without using get method. If I use get method, I will do something like this.editForm.get('ingredients'). Now, I want to use patchValue to update the FormArray.
Here is my formGroup code.

```
    this.editForm = new FormGroup({
      name: new FormControl(recip.name,[Validators.required]),
      imageUrl: new FormControl(recip.imagePath, [Validators.required]),
      description: new FormControl(recip.description ,[Validators.required]),
      ingredients: new FormArray(recip.ingredients.map((ing) => new 
                     FormGroup({name: new FormControl(ing.name), amount: new FormControl(ing.amount)})))});
```

Is there a way that I can patch value for the ingredients(eg, some code like this.editForm.patchValue({ingredients: something})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but you need take account that the "something" must be an array. If the array has more elements that elements in your FormArray, remove the elements of the formArray

e.g.

```
this.editForm.pacthValues(
    {ingredients:[
         {name:"name1",
          amount:100},
         {name:"name2",
          amount:200},
     ]
})
```

Only updated the two first elements in the FormArray. If the FormArray has more than two elements, remove the rest of elements, if the FormArray has less elements, the pathValue NOT add elements